# Allow down-voting documentation proposals

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

There are a lot tags on Stack Overflow which don’t really cover a topic you could write a documentation about. A lot of these are tags which are about a (named) concept that exists in multiple languages.

Currently, we get a lot documentation proposals for these topics. Here are just *some* examples (the list is almost endless):

- [alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alignment) – https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/alignment
- [api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/api) – https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/api
- [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apply) – https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/apply
- [commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commit) – https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/commit
- [crc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crc) – https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/crc
- [crop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crop) – https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/crop
- [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) – https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/list

None of these topics alone would be able to sustain a separate documentation tag, since they are very programming language or tool specific. It’s very unlikely that there will be any useful content there that wouldn’t fit better in another group.

Some would even—on their own—be off-topic for Stack Overflow. For example [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) would probably fit better on SuperUser, yet [there’s a proposal for it](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/cmd) which is about to be completed.

So I’d like to propose a functionality to **downvote** these proposals, just because they make no sense. At the moment, all you can do is say “yes, I commit to this topic”. But there really should be a “no, this topic does not make sense” button too.

Comment: It could require more veto votes than enthusiasts, no problem really.

Comment: Yeah, I’m not saying one vote should be enough to cancel it. I’d just like a way to disagree with proposals which is not possible at all right now.

Comment: "veto" very specifically means one single person or entity can overrule a decision. If you don't mean that one vote should be enough, don't call it veto, that's sure to lead to confusion. My first thought when I read your post was "hell no" for exactly that reason, even though I do agree with what you're trying to suggest.

Comment: @hvd Note that the meaning of the word *veto* does not necessarily implicate that only a single person/entity is involved with that decision. The meaning primarily focuses on the fact that you stop something from happening, maintaining the current status quo.

Comment: @hvd had to dust-off my dictionary, but "veto" as far I'm aware means "is the power to stop an action"